# Query Builder to return objects with oneToMany mapping as array

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, query-builder

I need to update my code to include Media, which is oneToMany unidirectional mapped in Object.php Entity. Ideally I need my code to return all objects even though without media, currently it only returns objects WITH media but it returns multiple results if there are multiple media items.

If you think I refactor the code and use something much simpler, than let me know - I didn't find a way to get the feed using the getRepo() and findBy() functions (no serialization?)

Here's my code:

```
// Build object QB
$emObject         = $this->objectService->getManager();
$qbObject         = $emObject->createQueryBuilder();
$qbObject->addSelect(['o.id', 'o.title', 'o.description', 'm as multimedia', 'c.id as category_id', 'c.name as category_name'])
        ->from('Application\Entity\Cms\Object', 'o')
        ->leftJoin('Application\Entity\Cms\Media', 'm', 'WITH', '1 = 1')
        ->leftJoin('o.media', 'om')
        ->leftJoin('Application\Entity\Cms\Category', 'c', 'WITH', '1 = 1')
        ->leftJoin('o.category', 'oc')
        ->andWhere('om.id = m.id')
        ->andWhere('oc.id = c.id')
        ->andWhere('o.member = :member')
        ->setParameter('member', $member);

$objectList = $qbObject->getQuery()->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

$viewModel->setVariables(['object' => $objectList]);

return $viewModel;
```

Which returns:

```
{
  "object": [
    {
      "multimedia": {
        "id": 22,
        "title": null,
        "url": "\/srv\/pois\/cms\/e9049aaac93ce96c81e16340027a804b.png"
      },
      "id": 34,
      "title": "imgTest",
      "description": "f",
      "category_id": 1,
      "category_name": "Chambres"
    },
    {
      "multimedia": {
        "id": 23,
        "title": null,
        "url": "\/srv\/pois\/cms\/ce0c7d669c567369485a01c65197943f.png"
      },
      "id": 34,
      "title": "imgTest",
      "description": "f",
      "category_id": 1,
      "category_name": "Chambres"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I need the multimedia objects to be in one array and only return 1 object, like:

```
{
  "object": [
    {
      "multimedia": {
          1: {
            "id": 22,
            "title": null,
            "url": "\/srv\/pois\/cms\/e9049aaac93ce96c81e16340027a804b.png"
          },
          0: {
            "id": 23,
            "title": null,
            "url": "\/srv\/pois\/cms\/ce0c7d669c567369485a01c65197943f.png"
          },
      }
      "id": 34,
      "title": "imgTest",
      "description": "f",
      "category_id": 1,
      "category_name": "Chambres"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always work with DQL queries without QueryBuilder. I think this is what you want:

```
$query = $this->entityManager->createQuery(
    "SELECT o, m FROM 'Application\Entity\Cms\Object' o JOIN o.multimedia m WHERE o.member = :member"
);
$query->setParameters(array('member' => $member));
$objects = $query->getResult();
```

I don't think it is more complicated than that.

In QueryBuilder it probably looks like this:

```
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('o', 'm')
   ->from('Application\Entity\Cms\Object', 'o')
   ->leftJoin('o.multimedia', 'm')
   ->where('o.member = :member')
   ->setParameter('member', $member);

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Please come back with details if this doesn't return what you want. I might be able to help out to get what you want.

Comment: What if you only want to return 'm' instead of 'o' and 'm'? When only selecting 'm' I get a ' Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias' error.

Comment: @J.Newb If you want to query `Member` entity it would be better to write a query in the `Member` entity-repository or you could rewrite the query and change the from clause to: `->from('Application\Entity\Cms\Member', 'm')`